# Search and pull the results by entering the initials of the word

Tags: android, search, searchbar

How can I filter the result even if the user only enters the initials. For example if in the list an item is "George Washington" if the user enters "g w" in the searchbox it shows the result. Below is my class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Listview Data
    String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                            "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                            "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    /**
     * Enabling Search Filter
     * */
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
        }
    });
   }    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and query the provider for results each time the user enters a letter.